# Store contents of a file with both integers and characters in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, stdin, rpn

I have a text file `input.txt` whose contents are of the form:

```
12 3 /
2 3 -
3 4 *
1 2 4 + - 5 * 7 /
```

My end goal is to read each line of the file and evaluate the given RPN expression. I have written the following code snippet to read the contents of the file from stdin and store it in a character array:

```
char expression[1000][256];
int i = 0;
while (fgets(expression[i], 256, stdin)) 
{   
    expression[i][strcspn(expression[i],"\r\n")] = 0;
    i++;
}
```

Now, I have all the lines in the array. My issue here is that I want to store these such that there are no spaces and each number (with all digits) or character is in a separate index.

For example, here, `expression[0][0]` is 1 and `expression[0][1]` is 2. But, I want `expression[0][0]` to be 12 and `expression[0][1]` to be 3, etc.

Comment: use `fscanf` instead of `fgets`.

Comment: That is part of the *parsing* you need to do to understand the expressions you read.

Comment: What if the number is `1234` and it doesn't fit in a `char`?

Comment: You cannot put 2 characters (`'1'` and `'2'`) in the space of 1 (`expression[0][0]`)

Comment: Also... don't use `fscanf` instead of `fgets`. Prefer `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()`.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to store the file, or even the line, and can just calculate as you read (add numbers to a "stack", do operations, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good work with your example so far! Thanks for posting a question that explains what you want, and making an attempt at solving it.

The main problem you've got is that you're storing an `array of array of chars`, when you need an `array of array of strings` (remember a `string` is a `char *`).

I've used the `[strtok][1]` method, which splits a string (using a NULL character) every time it hits one of the characters listed in its call. I then allocate memory, and copy the string into the array.

I made up some example code [(try it online)](https://onlinegdb.com/r13xSijUX) which does just this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* expression[1000][256];
    char buffer[256];
    int line = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, 256, stdin)) {
        int word = 0;
        char* token = strtok(buffer, " \r\n");
        do {
            expression[line][word] = calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(expression[line][word], token);
            word++;
        } while ((token = strtok(NULL, " \r\n")) != NULL);
        line++;;
    }
    printf("'%s', '%s', '%s'\n", expression[0][0], expression[0][1], expression[0][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works for 1000 lines, but when I use 5000+, segmentation fault occurs. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @fereydoon318 : yes, there are various ways to prevent this; one is to not store each line at all -- just process each line upon input (see e.g. the relevant aspects of the answer from chqrlie, below);  or, you can dynamically allocate memory as you read in more input lines -- dynamic memory allocation is a general need in C programming (and in other languages), and there are lots of resources on-line to guide you;  HTH

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to store the whole file in memory, but instead read one line at a time, evaluate it and print the result:

- define a buffer long enough for a line of input
- define an array of `int` to use as an RPN stack
- in a loop, read each line of input
- in a nested loop, using `strtok`, parse tokens:

  - if the token is a number, push its value onto the stack
  - if the token is an operator, perform this operation between the top 2 elements of the stack and store the result onto the stack after popping them.
- at the end of the line, print the value at the top of the stack

You want to perform simple checks for stack overflow and underflow.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[256];
    int stack[sizeof(buffer) / 2]; // no need for stack overflow check
    int i, sp, tos;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
        char *p = buffer, *token, *q;
        sp = -1;
        stack[++sp] = 1;
        stack[++sp] = 1;
        while ((token = strtok(p, " \t\r\n")) != NULL) {
            p = NULL;
            tos = stack[sp];
            if (!strcmp(token, "+")) {
                stack[--sp] += tos;
            } else
            if (!strcmp(token, "-")) {
                stack[--sp] -= tos;
            } else
            if (!strcmp(token, "*")) {
                stack[--sp] *= tos;
            } else
            if (!strcmp(token, "/")) {
                if (tos == 0 || (tos == -1 && stack[sp - 1] == INT_MAX)) {
                    printf("division overflow\n");
                    break;
                }
                stack[--sp] /= tos;
            } else
            if (!strcmp(token, "%")) {
                if (tos == 0 || (tos == -1 && stack[sp - 1] == INT_MAX)) {
                    printf("division overflow\n");
                    break;
                }
                stack[--sp] %= tos;
            } else {
                tos = strtol(token, &q, 0);
                if (q == token || *q != '\0') {
                    printf("invalid token: %s\n", token);
                    break;
                }
                stack[++sp] = tos;
            }
            if (sp < 2) {
                printf("stack underflow for %s\n", token);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (token == NULL) {
            for (i = 2; i <= sp; i++) {
                printf("%d%c", stack[i], i == sp ? '\n' : ' ');
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
12 3 /
2 3 -
3 4 *
1 2 4 + - 5 * 7 /
```

Output:

```
4
-1
12
-3
```